# Does External Backup Hardisk is usually slow?

Tags: windows-7, backup, external-hard-drive

I have purchased a new Seagate Backup Plus 1 TB 2.5" USB 3.0. I have notice that it copy files with a very low rate. I did some test using crystaldiskmark as follow.

[image]

as you can see it write in a very low rate specially with small files. 
recently I have to backup my data and I have notice that the maximum rate is ) 0.5MB to 1.6MB Maximum. specially when it comes with very small files (some local websites bunch of html and php's)

Some one told me that is the behavior of any Backup device .. they going too slow for durability and data verification. ... is That true? 
some people report the same problem on the same product without giving any explainations.

My question is does any backup device going slow in writing ??

Comment: If you connected it to a USB v. 1 or 2 port on your computer, it won't be able to use all the bandwidth allowed by its 3.0 port.

Comment: for sure I use it over my USB 3 port

Comment: Interesting that Seagate does not list speeds like RPM on even their data sheets for the products: http://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/backup-plus-fam/backup-plus-portable-drive-v2/en-us/docs/backup-plus-portable-drive-v3-ds1803-5-1312us.pdf  And this Amazon question for the product claims 5900RPM, maybe as low as 5400RPM: http://www.amazon.com/what-RPM-this-5400-7200/forum/Fx2R66VU018GS1I/Tx1K6STMNUHU00U/1/ref=cm_cd_ql_tlc_al?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00J0O5R2I  Seems like USB 3.0 for a drive like this is unnecessary, and could explain the slow speeds you're seeing here.

Comment: "does any backup device going slow in writing?" No there are lots of FAST backup targets.  What are you asking us exactly?  If you're concerned about your specific drive, do some further tests. Is it just as slow when used on another computer? Do other USB3 devices perform better than this on your computer?  Exactly which make/model of drive is in the enclosure?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I did some test as you can see this is the best result I could achieve. doing the test over my laptop giving me lower results. using 7core 8GB RAM in both desktop and laptop.

Comment: @armani could you please explain your idea ... sorry I don't get it.

Comment: One problem may be the cable. Make sure you have a proper sturdy USB3 cable.

Comment: @hsawires I don't have an idea, just noting the relevant info about your topic I found on the World Wide Web (the "net" as these crazy kids call it these days).

Comment: Backups tend to be slow (they are typically verified), and writing lots of small files is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of factors affect the speed of the backup.
USB speed, hard drive speed, software settings in the backup software, and the speed of computer being used to interface with the drive.

Backup software is typically slower due to the nature of what it's doing. Backing up files may take a long time depending on how many you have and where they're being read from. In your crystaldiskmark report, the speed is derived from how fast the controller board can process the bits, hard drive spindle speed, usb interface and host system speed.

Stating the above, best practice is to make sure you're using a USB 3.0 port on the computer with a usb cable connected to the backup drive. Do you know what speed your backup drive spins at? Faster speeds allow for faster random read access which will in turn speed up the transfer rate. Typical hard drives vary between 5400, 7200, and 10,000 rpm spindle speeds. Most larger desktop hard drives spin at 5400 or 7200.

In an optimal situation, you'll get faster backups by using faster devices and connections. Software settings can play a part in speed. If it verifies each file as it's written, this will slow down the transfer rate as it's doing a double read. Once from the source, and then again on the destination to confirm the crc checks before moving onto the next file.

I suspect that Seagate Backup Plus 1 TB 2.5" USB 3.0 is using a lower speed drive. To lower the cost for the unit, companies typically use lower speed drives for backup software. It's cheaper to mass produce and market as a backup solution.

Comment: Thank you @Tim for your answer actually My internal Hard disks copy with the rate of 60 to 70MB/s which is normal even I can get the same speed rate with an ordinary USB Rack

Comment: You're welcome. Understood. Just a side note. Internal harddrives are not using USB. You're very likely using a Sata cable and controller chip (which is much faster.)  I could be wrong and you're still on PATA(shutter to think) but USB data rates can't compete with SATA speeds.